# On click strike off items and move those items to the bottom of the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-bootstrap, strikethrough

I am trying to write a code where when a user clicks on an item on the list the item on that list should be strike off and and bring that item to the bottom of the list.

ItemList.js

```
 <ul className="list-group my-4">
        <h2 className="text-uppercase text-center custom-heading">todo list</h2>

        <div className="card card-body my-4 custom-card-bg">
          <pre>
            {items
              .slice(0)
              .reverse()
              .map(index => {
                return <ToDoItem key={index.id} name={index.name} />;
              })}
          </pre>
        </div>
      </ul>
```

The above given code is how the data is being added to the list

TodoItem.js

```
 <li className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex justify-content-between my-1 custom-input">
        <h6>{name}</h6>
        <div className="todo">
          <span className="mx-2 text-success">
            <i className="fas fa-pen" />
          </span>
          <span className="mx-2 text-danger">
            <i className="fas fa-trash" />
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
```

The above code is the styling of the item

App.js

```
 class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          items: [],
          currentItem: {
            name: "",
            id: ""
          },
          editItem: false
        };
      }

    addItems = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newItems = this.state.currentItem;
        if (newItems.name !== "") {
          const itemNames = [
            { ...newItems, isStriked: false },
            ...this.state.items
          ];
          this.setState({
            items: itemNames,
            currentItem: {
              name: "",
              id: ""
            },
            editItem: false
          });
        }
      };

      completedItem = id => {
        const complete = this.state.items.find(name => name.id === id);

        if (complete.isStriked === false)
          this.setState({
            items: [
              ...this.state.items.filter(name => name.id !== id),
              { ...complete, isStriked: true }
            ]
          });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div
              className="container-fluid d-flex vh-100 flex-column"
              style={{ height: "100vh" }}
            >
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-8 mt-4 mb-2 custom-row-bg">
                  <h2 className="text-center text-uppercase mt-3 custom-heading">
                    input todo
                  </h2>
                  <InputItems
                    name={this.state.currentItem.name}
                    handleInputChanges={this.handleInputChanges}
                    addItems={this.addItems}
                  />
                  <ItemList
                    items={this.state.items}
                    completedItem={this.completedItem}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

The above mentioned code explains how i decided to work on the striking an item of the method , i am unable understand how to make it work in the ItemList component?

Comment: First of all, you need an `onClick` listener on each of your items. Then you need to connect that to your `completedItem` function.

I suggest reading this https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up to learn how to do that (I linked to a certain section on that page, but I'd read the whole page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to have possibility to access onClick event in ItemList you need to make it ToDoItem component clickable:

```
<ToDoItem
    onClick={() => {
      console.log(index);
    }}
    key={index.id}
    name={index.name}
/>
```

In `ToDoItem`:

> In `ToDoItem` you are free to decide which element the click should start.

```
//...
const { name, onClick } = this.props;
//...
   <li
        onClick={onClick}
        className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex justify-content-between my-1 custom-input"
      >
//...
```

---

Update:

```
let { items } = this.state;
let to = 0;
let from = 0;
items = items.map((item, index) => {
   if (item.id === id) {
     item.completed = true;
     from = index;
   }
   return item;
});
// here i'm move the object in top. Because you use revert array.
// If you don't want to reverse array: to = items.length
items.splice(to, 0, items.splice(from, 1)[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you I understood this, but I am bit doubtful about how to strike off the element

Comment: You want to push down the completed tasks ? @thumalee

Comment: Yeah. And I am still unable to strike off items

Comment: Thank you. There's another requirement to get the newly added items to the top of the list. It was already implemented in my code. But with the changes made, all the newly added items move to the bottom of the list. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: see my comment above the `items.splice` in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210381/discussion-between-thumalee-and-fiodorov-andrei).